# Can someone from an English speaking country upload a list of Foursquare's Venue categories?

Tags: json, foursquare

I'm currently researching Foursquare's API and trying to download a list of supported venue categories as documented here: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/categories

However, as I am located in Germany, whenever I call that list of categories, I only receive the German translation of the categories as Json. I tried using an american proxy, but somehow Foursquare still figured out where I am truly located and delivered the German translation.

Could someone grab the Json with the English categories and upload it on bitbucket or something similar?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: It wants login details... I don't want to sign up. Also, this might be a better question for a chat room rather then SO proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uploaded a json tree to Google Drive. You should be able to view it through this link.

[link to JSON](http://pasted.co/4c8cd4af)

Comment: Thanks, but I think the json you grabbed was a different one. The categories Json is supposed to look like this (only in English): http://pasted.co/8967f556

Comment: Yes, I pasted the wrong stuff (I was doing a couple 4sq calls at the time). Updated answer with the english categories :)